# Site not accessible only in my home network

Tags: security, ip

My website, mmotter.com, and everything else on the host 72.10.48.224 is not accessable on my home work since I had a server problem a few months back. When I go on mobile internet or to another house I can access the site again. Pinging to the IP and site also works and my router shows no trace of blocked sites nor IP's.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause (and how to resolve)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to access the external IP 72.10.48.224 from the private network behind 72.10.48.224? This usually doesn't work. You'll need to access the server with its private IP address if you're on the local subnet. For example, your server may be at 192.168.0.10:80, but you may have NAT on your router set up to forward a port, so it's accessible from the outside world at 72.10.48.224:80.

Comment: If you go to https://72.10.48.224:8443/login_up.php3 it should work. Also if I open http://72.10.48.224:80 I get the following: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 72.10.48.224

Comment: Yes, it'll work for people outside the local subnet behind your own router. Works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really too familiar with network configurations. My IP is 84.194.187.142, and it used to work before I had the server problems. I'm not behind 72.10.48.224 as that's my webhost I'm trying to access. I think with the server problems it often kept loading for minutes and now it registered to some kind of blacklist? I can find no trace of such a thing on my router though. And no configuration was changed last 6 months, while it still worked.

Comment: Ok so I've called my webhost and apparently they were blocking me. They took me off the blacklist so it's resolved now. Thanks for the help though.